# violacion de segmento, no encuentro el por qué

Tags: c

tengo este en C código y me dá violación de segmento. no logro averiguar por         qué. quiero rellenar con ceros todos los elementos de la matriz.
parece que falla en el bucle que ha de rellenar la matriz, cuando lo comento compila y ejecuta, aunque no haga nada. si lo vuelvo a poner, compila bien, pero me sale el error de violación de segmento.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int **puntero_matriz;
    int filas;
    int columnas;
    int i;
    int j;

    filas = 6;
    columnas = 6;
    puntero_matriz = (int**)malloc(filas*sizeof(int*));
    if (puntero_matriz == NULL)
    {
        write(1, "No se ha podido reservar memoria 1", 35);
        return(1);
    }
    while (i < filas)
    {
        puntero_matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(columnas*sizeof(int));
        if (puntero_matriz == NULL)
        {
            write(1, "No se ha podido reservar memoria 2", 35);
            return (1);
        }
        i++;
    }
        /* vamos a intentar rellenar con ceros la matriz */
    i = 0;
    while (i < filas)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < columnas)
        {
            puntero_matriz[i][j] = 0;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Qué valor dirías que tiene `i`?

```
int i;

// ...

while (i < filas)
{
  // ...
}
```

Dado que es de tipo `int` tiene aproximadamente un 50% de posibilidades de ser mayor que 0 y otro 50% de ser menor que 0 y aproximadamente 1/(2^31) de posibilidades de ser exactamente 0.

Así pues:

- Si resulta que el valor de `i` es 0 tendrás una suerte que ni te la crees y funcionará todo bien.
- Si, en cambio el valor de `i` es menor que 0, por ejemplo -5000000, intentarás inicializar regiones de memoria que no te pertenecen... provocando una violación de segmento
- Si el valor de `i` resulta ser mayor que 0 entonces no se van a inicializar los punteros de `puntero_matriz` y, al intentar cualquier acceso acabarás accediendo a memroia que no te pertenece... provocando igualmente una violación de segmento.

La solución es tan sencilla (y complicada, por lo facil que resulta olvidarla), como inicializar las variables antes de usarlas:

```
int i=0;
```

Aunque también suele funcionar sorprendentemente bien eso de reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo:

```
for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: error de novato, siempre hay que inicializar las variables. Me lo tengo que grabar en la cabeza y no cometer otra vez el mismo error.